# How do I resolve the following issue : ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to server on '[AWS RDS endpoint]' (115)

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

This was the command I inputted

`mariadb -u [Root Username] -h [AWS RDS endpoint] -P 3306 -p`

It shows a field where I enter my password. It then shows nothing for a while and outputs the error code.

I have enabled all inbound ipv4 and ipv6 traffic in its attached security group. It is still not working. How do I fix this

Comment: Upon further research, I believe I have to connect to the VPC or implement VPC peering and then I'll be able to use the command to connect to the database. Is my understanding correct?